# External storage devices not listed while init script is running

Tags: init-script, automounting, external-hdd

I have an /etc/init.d script that is supposed to detect an external drive mounted at /dev/sda1, if it's there it mounts it. This works fine on my odroid device with the following specs:

```
pi@odroid64:~$ uname -a
Linux odroid64 3.14.65-73 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 2 08:21:02 BRT 2016 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

But when I run the same script on my raspberry pi with these specs:

```
pi@box:~ $ uname -a
Linux box 4.4.13-v7+ #894 SMP Mon Jun 13 13:13:27 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

It's unable to finish. By outputting `lsblk` in my script when I detect failure, I can see that the device has yet to appear under `/dev/sda` by the time the script is running. Here is the output of `lsblk` when the script is ran

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 mmcblk0 179:0 0 7.4G 0 disk 
 ├─mmcblk0p1 179:1 0 63M 0 part /boot 
 └─mmcblk0p2 179:2 0 7.3G 0 part /
```

And here is the output of `lsblk` by the time I login

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0 111.8G  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0   7.4G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0    63M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0   7.3G  0 part /
```

So if, after I login, I run

`sudo /etc/init.d/usbstorage restart`

It mounts the drive as expected, and `lsblk` outputs

```
pi@camio-box:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0 111.8G  0 part /mnt/usbstorage
mmcblk0     179:0    0   7.4G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0    63M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0   7.3G  0 part /
```

And mounts the drive as expected.

So I think that I have the wrong headers on my init-script, like I'm not waiting for the system to detect external drives before the script it being ran. Here is the header for my script.

```
#! /bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          usbstorage
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $named $portmap
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: Mounts an external drive to /mnt/usbstorage for the cam process
### END INIT INFO
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't exactly figure out what went wrong, but I found a much easier way of accomplishing the same thing. Simply add this line to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/usbstorage auto defaults,user,rw,uid=pi,gid=pi 0 0
```

the `auto` keyword will detect the device formatting automatically, which is what my last script was doing. Setting the uid and gid explicitly makes it work with FAT-formatted drives as well.

Comment: follow-up: This will actually not work as expected. See this question for more information http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314368/etc-fstab-entry-to-automount-drive-in-either-ext234-or-fat-formatting